# Cannot start service apache on laragon

Tags: php, apache, xampp, laragon

Everything was ok before. Today I tried to start laragon apache and I got the following error :

> httpd: Syntax error on line 546 of
>
> C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15/conf/httpd.conf:
>
> Syntax error on line 1 of
>
> C:/laragon/etc/apache2/fcgid.conf: Cannot load
>
> C:/laragon/etc/apache2/modules/mod_fcgid-2.3.9-Win32-VC14.so
>
> into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

[image]

I have tried to change PHP versions, but it didn't help.
What should I do to start apache withour this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was given by one of [Laragon's administrators](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/1949/error-starting-apache-server-after-changing-php-version/2)

You need to use a PHP Thread Safe version. The PHP NTS (non thread safe) versions are NOT compatible with Laragon.

https://forum.laragon.org/topic/166/tutorial-how-to-add-another-php-version-php-7-4-php-8-0-updated/1

You must also make sure that the VC of both PHP & Apache are the same.

Comment: 8.1.1 nts does work for me on windows 11 though

Answer (score 5):

If you are finding when trying to switch from php7 to php8 on Laragon here is a quick fix goto C:\laragon\etc\apache2

**open mod_php.conf** on line 2 change **php8_module** to **php_module**

```
# This file is auto-generated, so please keep it intact.
LoadModule php8_module "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64"
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

change this above to

```
# This file is auto-generated, so please keep it intact.
LoadModule php_module "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64"
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```