# laragon error appears description: service apache can not start. reason:

Tags: windows, laragon

I have changed the php laragon version from 8.1.10 to 7.4.32, after changing a pop up like this appears. [I have followed this same method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775628/cannot-start-service-apache-on-laragon)

i found the following problem

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 24 of C:/laragon/etc/apache2/fcgid.conf: Wrapper C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.32/php-cgi.exe cannot be accessed: (720002) The system cannot find the file specified.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iO4q.png)

how do you get it to run? If you use Laragon's built-in php it can run

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue is due to a missing "php-cgi" file in your "7php.4.32" folder. When downloading PHP, make sure to verify that the required "php-cgi" file is included in the package. Check the downloaded files to ensure the presence of this essential file. Look you error message. [image]